Receive notifications when the printer status changes
I would like to develop an application that displays a message when the printer prints.
I created a small test application for the console, but for some reason I don't get any notification of a change in the printer state. It should be noted that when I checked the job status in this way (with JOB_NOTIFY_TYPE and JOB_NOTIFY_FIELD_STATUS), notifications about the job status were indeed received.
Does the printer not send notifications? (And is it related to the printer type and/or driver?)
Here is the code to test:
program PrinterMonitor;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Winapi.WinSpool;

const
  PrinterField: WORD = PRINTER_NOTIFY_FIELD_STATUS;

var
  PrinterName: string;
  hStopEvent: THandle;
  hPrinter: THandle;
  hPrintNotify: THandle;
  pno: TPrinterNotifyOptions;
  pnot: TPrinterNotifyOptionsType;
  pni: Pointer;
  dwChange: DWORD;
  WaitHandles: array[0..1] of THandle;

function CtrlHandler(fdwCtrlType: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  Result := False;
  case fdwCtrlType of
    CTRL_C_EVENT, CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT:
    begin
      SetEvent(hStopEvent);
      Result := True;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure GetPrinterNotifyData(const Info: TPrinterNotifyInfo);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Info.Count - 1 do
  begin
    with Info.aData[I] do
    begin
      case wType of
        PRINTER_NOTIFY_TYPE:
        begin
          case Field of
            PRINTER_NOTIFY_FIELD_STATUS: WriteLn('Printer status: ', NotifyData.adwData[0]);
          end;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

begin
  if ParamCount < 1 then
  begin
    WriteLn('No printer name specified.');
    Exit;
  end;
  PrinterName := ParamStr(1); //pass a printer name as argument

  OpenPrinter(PWideChar(PrinterName), hPrinter, nil);
  if hPrinter = 0 then
  begin
    WriteLn('Cannot open printer "', PrinterName, '". ErrorCode: ', GetLastError);
    Exit;
  end;

  pnot.wType := PRINTER_NOTIFY_TYPE;
  pnot.Count := 1;
  pnot.pFields := @PrinterField;

  pno.Version := 2;
  pno.Count := 1;
  pno.pTypes := @pnot;

  hStopEvent := CreateEvent(nil, True, False, nil);
  if hStopEvent = 0 then
  begin
    WriteLn('Cannot create stop event. ErrorCode: ', GetLastError);
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    Exit;
  end;

  hPrintNotify := FindFirstPrinterChangeNotification(hPrinter, 0, 0, @pno);
  if hPrintNotify = 0 then
  begin
    WriteLn('Cannot start monitoring. ErrorCode: ', GetLastError);
    ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
    CloseHandle(hStopEvent);
    Exit;
  end;

  WaitHandles[0] := hStopEvent;
  WaitHandles[1] := hPrintNotify;

  SetConsoleCtrlHandler(@CtrlHandler, True); // handling CTRL+C & close console events for stop monitoring

  WriteLn('==== Monitor started ====');
  while True do
  begin
    case WaitForMultipleObjects(2, @WaitHandles, False, INFINITE) of
      WAIT_OBJECT_0: // hStopEvent signalled
      begin
        WriteLn('==== Monitor stopped ====');
        Break;
      end;
      WAIT_OBJECT_0+1: // hPrintNotify signalled
      begin
        if not FindNextPrinterChangeNotification(hPrintNotify, dwChange, nil, pni) then
        begin
          WriteLn('Cannot get notify changes data.');
          Break;
        end;
        GetPrinterNotifyData(PPrinterNotifyInfo(pni)^);
        FreePrinterNotifyInfo(PPrinterNotifyInfo(pni));
      end;
      else
      begin
        WriteLn('Wait failed');
        Break;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  FindClosePrinterChangeNotification(hPrintNotify);
  ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
  CloseHandle(hStopEvent);
end.


I link to some examples of working code in this answer. Best to monitor other notifications that you know are sent - just to ensure you have working code first.

@Nick, I specifically stated in the question - this code works on the job status

"is it related to the printer type and/or driver" In case the answer is yes: can you add this info to your question?

When I run your code and then pause and resume the print queue, it works fine:
==== Monitor started ====
Printer status: 131073
Printer status: 131072

The value 131073 = 0x20001, which is comprised of the enums:
PRINTER_STATUS_TONER_LOW | PRINTER_STATUS_PAUSED


The truth is, I didn't try to check delay and renewal of print queues, I wanted to get the values ​​PRINTER_STATUS_PRINTING when the printer is printing, or PRINTER_STATUS_DOOR_OPEN when the tray is open, etc. It is not clear to me yet why there are no notifications when such events occur.

Only the associated printer driver (and software) components know how to communicate with the physical printer. They can set the print queue status, but rarely do so - unless for a high-end printer. The cheap printer that I use only flags toner low, not the other statuses you're interested in. (FYI, see my other answer here about some printer statuses flagged on a job status or printer attribute.) What printer are you using, and how is it connected? Your best bet might be SNMP.
